# Refactoring and Cleaning Up Code in React - Dealing with Conditions and Wrapper Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coding-style, refactoring, code-cleanup

Is there a cleaner way to do a condition in a react component? Say I have something like this:

```
<Track>
  <ProductLink>
    <Image ... /> 
    <Typography ...>{...}</Typography>
    <Typography ...>{...}</Typography>
  </ProductLink>
</Track>
```

And with conditions, it would be like this:

```
{condition ? <Track><ProductLink> : <> }
  <Image ... /> 
  <Typography ...>{...}</Typography>
  <Typography ...>{...}</Typography>
{condition ? </ProductLink></Track> : </> }
```

Is there another way of doing the condition?
If condition is met, have the Track and ProductLink component, if not, just display the Fragment component.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommending hoisting the `Track` and `ProductLink` into a reusable component -- that way you'll simplify it to one condition.

For example:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Track from "./path/to/Track";
import ProductLink from "./path/to/ProductLink";   

const TrackProduct = ({ children, isTracked }) => (
 isTracked 
  ? <Track>
      <ProductLink>
       {children}
      </ProductLink>
    </Track>
  : children
);

TrackProduct.proptTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  isTracked: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default TrackProduct;
```

Then import the above reusable component and control it via `state`:

```
import React from "react";
import TrackProduct from "./path/to/TrackProduct";
import Image from "./path/to/Image";
import Typography from "./path/to/Typography";
import Button from "./path/to/Button";

class Example extends Component {
  state = { isTracked: false };

  toggleTrack = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ track: !prevState.isTracked }))

  render = () => (
    <TrackProduct isTracked={this.state.isTracked}>
      <Image ... /> 
      <Typography ...>{...}</Typography>
      <Typography ...>{...}</Typography>
      <Button onClick={this.toggleTrack}>
        {!this.state.isTracked ? "Track" : "Untrack"} Product
      </Button>
    </TrackProduct>
  )
};

export default Example;
```

---

If the above doesn't quite work and/or is too repetitive, then you can use a render prop that passes some of its own state and class fields to a child function to be controlled (I prefer this method over wrapper HOCs, since they're easier to test against).

For example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Track from "./path/to/Track";
import ProductLink from "./path/to/ProductLink";   

class TrackProduct extends Component {
  state = { isTracked: false };

  toggleTrack = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ track: !prevState.isTracked }))

  render = () => {
    const renderedChildren = this.props.children({ 
      isTracked: this.state.isTracked,   
      toggleTrack: this.toggleTrack
    });

    return (
      isTracked 
        ? <Track>
            <ProductLink>
              {renderedChildren}
            </ProductLink>
          </Track>
        : renderedChildren
    )
  };
};

TrackProduct.proptTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default TrackProduct;
```

Then import the above reusable render prop component and control it via TrackProduct's passed down props (`isTracked` and `toggleTrack`):

```
import React from "react";
import TrackProduct from "./path/to/TrackProduct";
import Image from "./path/to/Image";
import Typography from "./path/to/Typography";
import Button from "./path/to/Button";

const Example = () => (
  <TrackProduct>
    {({ isTracked, toggleTrack }) => (
      <>
        <Image ... /> 
        <Typography ...>{...}</Typography>
        <Typography ...>{...}</Typography>
        <Button onClick={toggleTrack}>
          {!isTracked ? "Track" : "Untrack"} Product
        </Button>
      </>
    )}
  </TrackProduct>
);

export default Example;
```

More info about render props can be found in this [Phoenix ReactJS conference talk](https://youtu.be/BcVAq3YFiuc?t=625).